# Combining gsub calls and remove character after last instance of a string

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string:

```
time <- "2017-05-30T09:20:00-08:00"
```

I was to use `gsub` to produce this:

`"2017-05-30 09:20:00"`

Here is what I have so far:

```
time2 <- gsub("T", " ", time)
gsub("\\-.*", "", time2)
```

Two questions -

1. How do remove all characters after the *last* instance of `-`?
2. How do I combine these two statements into one?

Comment: Can you shed any light on what the `-8:00` is doing? This is converting the time back to GMT somehow?

Comment: Using capture groups: `gsub("(.*)T(.*)-.*", "\\1 \\2", time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single call to a `sub` with a spelled out regex to *capture* the parts you are interested in, and just match everything else. Then, use **replacement backreferences** `\1` and `\2` in the replacement pattern to re-insert those two captured subparts:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1Ikv4/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group 1: 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and then 2 digits
- `T` - a `T` letter
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 2: 2 digis, `:`, 2 digits, `:` and 2 digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the string end.

[R online demo](http://ideone.com/KX20ma):

```
time_s <- "2017-05-30T09:20:00-08:00"
sub("^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*", "\\1 \\2", time_s)
## => [1] "2017-05-30 09:20:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use functions that convert to `DateTime`

```
library(anytime)
format(anytime(time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2017-05-30 09:20:00"
```